# OCSP response sign algorithm

Tags: openssl

I have a question regarding OCSP's answer.
I need to configure the server so that the response signature algorithm is sha384withRSAencryption. Unfortunately, I didn't find the options in the OpenSSL documentation:
[OpenSSL ocsp documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man1/ocsp.html)

> I know how to configure the signing certificate, but the OCSP response signature algorithm does not change.

Сommands used to start the OCSP responder:

> openssl ocsp -index <index.txt>  
> -port 7777 
> -rsigner <ca_cert.crt> 
> -rkey <ca_key.key> 
> -CA <ca_cert.crt> 
> -text

Commands used to send OCSP reauest:

> openssl ocsp -issuer <issuer_cert.crt> 
> -trust_other 
> -verify_other <ca_cert.crt> 
> -CAfile <ca_cert.crt> 
> -url http://localhost:7777 
> -text 
> -cert <cert.crt> 
> -no_nonce

How i can configure OCSP response signature algorithm?
Do i need add some options to responder or request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer. To configure reponder signature algorithm you should to add next option:

> -rmd sha384

And responder script will be like that:

> openssl ocsp -index <index.txt> 
> -port 7777 
> -rmd sha384 
> -rsigner <ca_cert.crt> 
> -rkey <ca_key.key> 
> -CA <ca_cert.crt> 
> -text